# Supersets of unit ball in infite dimension

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space with infinite dimension. Is it true that every superset of the unit ball $B_X(0)$ in $X$ is not compact. In finite dimensions this is not true. I couldn't find any counterexample in infinite dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In normed space, a closed subset of a compact set must be compact. And we know that in infinite-dimensional Banach space the closed unit ball is not compact.

Comment: I'm looking for supersets of the unit ball. So what about sets $E$ so that $B_X\subset E$, where $B_X$ is the unit ball in $X$. Can we find such a set so that $E$ is compact or is this impossible ?

Comment: Assume that $E$ is compact, then it is closed, so $\overline{B}_{X}\subseteq E$, this implies also that $\overline{B}_{X}$ is compact, a contradiction to the infinite-dimensionality.